# Merging Excel sheets in Pandas with different dimensions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, join, merge

I have one Excel file called SuperStoreUS, data in there is about orders, prices and dates, and I have 3 different sheets: "Orders", "Returns", "Users", I want to merge them, but the dimensions are different. Lets say on sheet "Orders" we have column called Region  and in Users as well, only in "Users" we have 4 regions in global and 4 managers, I want to add it to one table and each time there is in a row lets say "West" I want in newly created table to be shown name of the manager for that region, same thing with sheet "Returns", we can connect it though OrderID with "Orders" but I dont know how.
[image: Users sheet]

[image: Orders sheet]

[image: Return id]

So I have this part of a code, but I'm not sure whether to use concat, join or merge

```
excel_path = r'C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\PythonFiles\Omega\SuperStoreUS.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name=None)
df_order = df.get('Orders')
df_returns = df.get('Returns')
df_users = df.get('Users')
df_n = pd.merge(df_order, df_users, on = "Region", how = "right")
df_n.head(20)
```

It seems that I'm loosing rows like this
and I dont want that, I want simply to merge them/

Comment: Do you want to create a single dataframe or do you want multiple? You say, *I want to merge them...* which suggests you want only a single dataframe but you also say, *I want in newly created table to be shown...*

Comment: Yess, in a single data frame, it can be names as a new data frame, but yes, I want them in one DF.

Comment: I tried doing this ` df_n = df_order.merge(df_users, on = "Region").merge(df_returns, on = "Order ID") ` , but it gave me only 15 rows